# Handle events raised from a dynamically loaded .NET dll

Tags: .net, plugins, dll

I have a VB.NET application which loads some dll files dynamically. All plugins are in a folder and my application loads all dll files from this folder.

In order to load a dll, I use the following code

```
_aAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(_File.FullName)
_aClass = _aAssembly.GetType(_AssemblyName & "." & ClassName)
_aAddin = Activator.CreateInstance(_aClass)
```

To run a method in this dll

```
Function RunMethod(ByVal Method As String, Optional ByVal Paramter() As Object = Nothing) As Object
    Dim aMethode As MethodInfo = _aClass.GetMethod(Method)
    Return aMethode.Invoke(_aAddin, Paramter)
End Function
```

This works perfect. But now I'd like to fire an event in my dll files and handle them in my main application. I started with adding the following code to my dll:

```
Public Shared Event GotSomethingToSend(Str As String)
```

And I fire the event with

```
RaiseEvent GotSomethingToSend(Str)
```

My problem is that I have no clue on how to "catch" the event in my main application. Is it even possible? 
I already tried `GetEvent()`:

```
Dim ei As EventInfo = _aAssembly.GetType(_AssemblyName & "." & ClassName).GetEvent("GotSomethingToSend")
```

But I didn't get very far... Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

You already have an `EventInfo` instance, you just need to wire it up to a method in your app. Try calling [EventInfo.AddEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx), e.g.

```
ei.AddEventHandler(_aAddin, DirectCast(AddressOf MyGotSomethingToSendHandlerMethod, GotSomethingToSendEventHandler))

Private Delegate Sub GotSomethingToSendEventHandler(str As String)

Private Sub MyGotSomethingToSendHandlerMethod(str As String)
    ' TODO: Event handling code.
End Sub
```

Note - The type cast is required because the compiler can't infer the correct delegate type in this late-binding scenario.

**ADDENDUM**

Although the above code should do what you want, Microsoft recommend that you stick to their common standard for all event signatures (`sender As Object, e As TEventArgs`). If you want to do this, you can re-design the code as follows:

```
' Encapsulate all event data in a dedicated class.
Public Class GotSomethingToSendEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property Data As String
End Class

' Handler method now looks like this.
Private Sub MyGotSomethingToSendHandlerMethod(sender As Object, e As GotSomethingToSendEventArgs)
End Sub

' Wire-up code now looks like this.
ei.AddEventHandler(_aAddin, DirectCast(AddressOf MyGotSomethingToSendHandlerMethod, EventHandler(Of GotSomethingToSendEventArgs)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would the handler method look like? Because I get an error when I use a simple `sub`: 
'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'System.Delegate' because type 'System.Delegate' is declared 'MustInherit' and cannot be created

Comment: `Private Sub MyGotSomethingToSendHandlerMethod(Str As String)` should work fine...

Comment: Updated answer now that I've actually tried it in the IDE. :-)

Comment: Thanks again. That looks much better. However... Something's still wrong. The AddEventHandler method leads to a System.ArgumentException. The program doesn't crash, but no more code is executed. So if I add a messagebox after calling AddEventHandler, it's never shown. This gets really complicated. Maybe I have to overthink my concept...

Comment: It does seem all very late-bound, and I think that's where the problem lies. When I write plugins, I make them implement a single interface and interact with them entirely through that interface. If I need a callback, I just pass a strongly-typed delegate to the plugin via the interface.

Comment: Hmm okay. Thanks for all your help! I'll try to overthink it and read myself more into these things.